# I want to extract the strings from file name xxARCRPT_ES_US.rtf

Tags: ksh

I want to extract the strings from file name `xxARCRPT_ES_US.rtf` to assign to the

```
lobcode=XXARCRPT ,LANG=es, TERITORY=US
```

Note: I have to implement this in the .ksh file

For example,

```
file name: xxARCRPT_ES_US.rtf
----------> lobcode=XXARCRPT   (must be in upper case)
----------> LANG=es            (must be in lower case)
----------> TERITORY=US        (must be in upper case)
```

Can anyone help me in getting the strings into 3 variables.

Thank You,
Arun

Comment: Can I dissuade you from using the variable named `LANG`, and call it something else?

Comment: Please see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts

Answer (score 0):

```
filename=xxARCRPT_ES_US.rtf
```

This strips off everything following the first underscore and stores it in `lobcode`, then runs it through `tr` to upper-case it:

```
lobcode=${filename%%_*}
lobcode=$(printf '%s' "$lobcode" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')
```

This sets up an intermediate, temporary variable with the contents of the variable following the first underscore:

```
rest=${filename#*_}
```

This assigns the language prefix (everything before the first underscore) to the variable `language`, then lower-cases it:

```
language=${rest%%_*}
language=$(printf '%s' "$language" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')
```

This strips off the leading text before the first underscore, then strips off everything following the first period, then assigns *that* to the variable `territory`, then upper-cases it:

```
rest=${rest#*_}
territory=${rest%%.*}
territory=$(printf '%s' "$territory" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')
```

... and then clean up the temporary variable:

```
unset rest
```